# Pi Filter Design / Realization with 915MHz u.Fl

Tags: rf, filter, antenna, layout

I'm putting a u.Fl connector into a new LoRaWAN design (915MHz). Apologies ahead of time if the scope of my questions are too wide for one post, but I think it's all closely related.

I'm going to locate the connector quite close to the antenna pin of the module I will be using; maybe a trace length of 250mil at worst. I'm looking around the web it seems like a good practice to include a π-filter in series with the antenna trace. I've gleaned that it's a CYA-strategy if you find a problem during certification testing to have an out that you can tune the filter if your emissions are failing; and it seems like generally you just DNP the capacitors in the filter as a first pass. So I have a couple of practical questions about this implementation.

1. How much does this matter for 915 MHz / should I even put it in at all?
2. The guidance I've seen is pretty wishy-washy about component values, but, [this calculator](https://www.eeweb.com/tools/pi-match) seems to think about 5nH is what the inductor value should be for 50-ohm characteristic impedance in and out at 915MHz. Not sure what Q-factor is there so just accepted the default of three. Does that pass the sniff test?
3. Should the filter be located closer to the transmitter or should it be closer to the antenna, or (it would seem unlikely to me but) somewhere in between? At the total distance I need to travel, it seems like it's probably irrelevant, but I thought I'd ask.
4. How much does the physical form factor of the components in the filter matter? Is it OK to use 0805 parts? 0603? 0402? In my mind bigger is better for reliability in manufacturing, but I can imagine parasitic inductance or whatever being a factor with bigger geometries. Again, is this something to be concerned about at 915MHz?
5. As far as the trace to the u.Fl connector goes, I could make a microstrip co-planar waveguide for 50-ohms. Using this calculator I came up with 18mil (0.4572mm) width, 10mil (0.254mm) gap, using relative dielectric constant of 3.9, and a dielectric thickness of 9mil (0.23mm) for this 4-layer design with a ground plane directly below the antenna feed trace. put ground stitching vias around the feed trace, and cutout the ground (and other) plane directly under the u.Fl connector "slot" where the coax connects as shown in below recommendation I found. Again, just wondering if I'm overthinking it.

[image]
[ref](https://assets.lairdtech.com/home/brandworld/files/BT8x0%20PCB%20RF%20Design%20v1_0.pdf) * note, I'm treating this as a generic reference, not a specific part I'm using.

**Update #1**

I went ahead and routed a feed line through a Pi-filter, using 0603 parts, here's what it looks like:

[image]

Comment: If you know the 3OI of your Tx then you know how much filtering is needed for harmonics at lower Tx levels.

Comment: Saturn PCB.exe tells me traces of 8:1 = L: W ratio are 0.5nH/mm and long tracks of 80:1=L:W are 1nH/mm assuming a certain weight copper and frequency